# How to write table data into a nested struct in Go

Tags: go, struct, slice, nested-json

**Summary**

I am trying to write data from several postgres tables into a nested Go struct for the purpose of returning a single json response to a GET request within my web app.

**Questions**

1. Is the way I'm declaring a nested struct reasonable from a Go best practices perspective, or is there a reason I should avoid this method and do it another way?
2. What am I doing wrong in **Step 3** to prevent my code from working? *(I fear the answer is 'everything')*

**What I've got so far**

1. I've declared my struct of structs

```
type MainObject struct {

    SubObjects []struct {
        SpecificDetail string `json:"specific-detail"`
                           }  `json:"sub-object"`

    ...(other []structs)...
}
```

2. I've retrieved rows from the tables

```
func getMainObjectHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    
    ...(database connnection)...
    
    MainObjectID := r.URL.Query().Get("moid")
    if MainObjectID != "null" {
        NewMainObject := MainObject{}
        SubObjectDetail_rows, err := db.Query("SELECT specific_detail from the_table WHERE moid= '" + MainObjectID + "'")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("could not execute query: %v", err)
        }
        
        ...(other db.Query rows)...
```

3. I've tried (and failed) to build the row data into the struct.

```
        for SubObjectDetail_rows.Next() {
            SpecificDetail := NewMainObject.SubObject.SpecificDetail{}
            SubObjectDetail_rows.Scan(&SpecificDetail)
            SubObject = append(SubObject, SpecificDetail)
        }
        NewMainObject = append(MainObject, SubObject)
        defer persona_rows.Close()
```

4. Finally, I've set up Marshal and write.

```
        NMOListBytes, err := json.Marshal(NewMainObject)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(fmt.Errorf("Error: %v", err))
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        w.Write(NMOListBytes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, please use placeholders when creating your SQL query to avoid injections:

```
// db.Query("SELECT specific_detail from the_table WHERE moid= '" + MainObjectID + "'")  // not this
db.Query("SELECT specific_detail from the_table WHERE moid=?", MainObjectID)
```

Unless you're using a framework like `GORM` you can't `Scan()` into a single struct value.
From [the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Rows.Scan):

> Scan copies the columns in the current row into the values pointed at
> by dest. The number of values in dest must be the same as the number
> of columns in Rows.

It looks like you're pulling JSON from a DB query, as you're only querying one column, so you probably want:

```
var bs []byte // get raw JSON bytes

err = SubObjectDetail_rows.Scan(&bs) 
if err != nil { /* always check errors */ }
```

and then unmarshal them to your struct:

```
err = json.Unmarshal(bs, &SpecificDetail)
if err != nil { /* ... */ }
```